# Is it possible to use the Kindle Fire's browser in a full screen mode?

Tags: browser, amazon-kindle-fire

So we got a Kindle Fire at work today, and I've been playing with it a bit to see what all it can do. One thing that I thought would be neat is to try our new web-based application in the Fire's Silk browser to see how it stacks up against some of our other devices (like my Xoom and the Galaxy Tab 7).

In general it's okay, but it's starting to really bug me that the status bar is always visible when I'm using Silk, instead of filling the whole screen. There's also a tab bar at the top that I can't get to go away, and the bottom menu bar appears to be persistently visible. When you read a book, all of this goes away and then you bring it back by touching the screen, and I really like the full screen look.

Is there any way to run Silk in a "full screen" mode, specifically one which hides the top status bar? I checked around in the settings and whatnot and haven't been able to find anything. Bonus points: Is there a way to hide the tab bar or the bottom menu bar similar to the book reading app?

Comment: I haven't found any way to remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to have been added in v6.2.2 of the Kindle Fire's system firmware. I updated today and there is now a fullscreen button at the far right of the bottom menu bar in the stock browser. Pressing it hides the menu bar, the status bar, and the tab bar.